# How can I draw a table with many text?

Tags: tables, tabularx

I need my table to have a structure like this:
[image]

I never had this much text on a table on any of my latex documents before so I'm lost here. This is how I did it, I don't know how I should do this.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{units}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
\usepackage{xurl}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{refstyle}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\usepackage[swedish]{babel} 
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}

\begin{table}[!ht]
\centering{\begin{tabular}{llrll} 
\hline \hline
Steg & Action & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Maskin} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Verktyg} \\
\hline \hline
1 & Börja med att kapa av en rimlig bit för mobilstället & Kapsåg & Klämmare \\
2 & Ställ metallbiten på kapsågsmaskinen så att längden blir 197,5 mm långt och den ska spännas fast med en klämmare. Detta är bara för att komma nära längden så mycket som möjligt. Sedan görs samma metod för bredden, som är 50 mm. & Kapsåg & Klämmare \\
3 & Ställ x, y och z för fräsmaskinen så att metallbiten får den exakta längden och bredden. & Fräsmaskin & Klämmare \\
4 & Kap av två av kanterna så att de två kanterna får en rundare kant och inte 90 grader. & Fräsmaskin & Klämmare \\
5 & Biten ska böjas från längden 114,3 mm tills den böjda delen är vinklad 78 grader mot den andra halvan. & Kantvikmaskin & Vinkelinstrument \\
6 & Sidan där de två kanterna kapades i steg 4 ska nu böjas tills den är 125 grader vinklat mot den oböjda positionen. & Kantvikmaskin & Vinkelinstrument \\
7 & De två hålen borras och de ska vara parallellt lagda med varandra mellan ett avstånd på 34 mm, och 8 mm från vardera kanter. Hålen ska ha en diameter på 8mm och centrumen bör först markeras med en större pinnfräs innan 8mm pinnfräsen borras igenom metallplåten. & Borrmaskin & Pinnfräs (8mm) \\
\hline
\end{tabular}}
\caption{De kända variablerna som krävs för att få fram figurens tyngdpunkt där $A$ står för area.}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you employ a `tabularx` environment, set its width to `\textwidth`, and employ the `X` column type for the 2nd column; use the plain `l` column type for the other columns. Last but not least, I wouldn't use doubled-up `\hline` directives. Instead, I'd load the booktabs package and employ its user macros `\toprule`, `\midrule`, and `\bottomrule` to draw well-spaced horizontal rules.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[swedish]{babel} 

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{units}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
\usepackage{xurl}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{refstyle}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}

\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs} % <-- new
\usepackage{hyperref} % load this package last

\begin{document}

%\maketitle

\section{Introduction}

\begin{table}[!ht]
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} lXll @{}} 
\toprule
Steg & Action & Maskin & Verktyg \\
\midrule
1 & Börja med att kapa av en rimlig bit för mobilstället 
  & Kapsåg & Klämmare \\
2 & Ställ metallbiten på kapsågsmaskinen så att längden blir 197,5 mm långt och den ska spännas fast med en klämmare. Detta är bara för att komma nära längden så mycket som möjligt. Sedan görs samma metod för bredden, som är 50 mm. 
  & Kapsåg & Klämmare \\
3 & Ställ x, y och z för fräsmaskinen så att metallbiten får den exakta längden och bredden. 
  & Fräsmaskin & Klämmare \\
4 & Kap av två av kanterna så att de två kanterna får en rundare kant och inte 90 grader. 
  & Fräsmaskin & Klämmare \\
5 & Biten ska böjas från längden 114,3 mm tills den böjda delen är vinklad 78 grader mot den andra halvan. 
  & Kantvikmaskin & Vinkelinstrument \\
6 & Sidan där de två kanterna kapades i steg 4 ska nu böjas tills den är 125 grader vinklat mot den oböjda positionen. 
  & Kantvikmaskin & Vinkelinstrument \\
7 & De två hålen borras och de ska vara parallellt lagda med varandra mellan ett avstånd på 34 mm, och 8 mm från vardera kanter. Hålen ska ha en diameter på 8mm och centrumen bör först markeras med en större pinnfräs innan 8mm pinnfräsen borras igenom metallplåten. 
  & Borrmaskin & Pinnfräs (8mm) \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\caption{De kända variablerna som krävs för att få fram figurens tyngdpunkt där $A$ står för area.}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you sir!!

Comment: @Mico: Will's exact expression is  ‘Last, not least’.

Answer (score 1):

Simply use `tabularx`. I added some improvemennts (e.g. using the rules from `booktabs`, which have variable thickness, and add some vertical padding. Also, load `hyperref as la last package (very few exceptions), and loading`  inputenc`is not necessary, if youyr installation is comparatively recent, as`utf8` has been  the default for more than two years.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[swedish]{babel}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{units}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
\usepackage{xurl}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{tabularx, booktabs}
\usepackage{refstyle}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

%\maketitle

\section{Introduction}

\begin{table}[!ht]
\centering
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{lXrll}
\toprule \midrule
Steg & Action & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Maskin} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Verktyg} \\
\midrule \midrule
1 & Börja med att kapa av en rimlig bit för mobilstället & Kapsåg & Klämmare \\ \addlinespace
2 & Ställ metallbiten på kapsågsmaskinen så att längden blir 197,5 mm långt och den ska spännas fast med en klämmare. Detta är bara för att komma nära längden så mycket som möjligt. Sedan görs samma metod för bredden, som är 50 mm. & Kapsåg & Klämmare \\ \addlinespace
3 & Ställ x, y och z för fräsmaskinen så att metallbiten får den exakta längden och bredden. & Fräsmaskin & Klämmare \\ \addlinespace
4 & Kap av två av kanterna så att de två kanterna får en rundare kant och inte 90 grader. & Fräsmaskin & Klämmare \\ \addlinespace
5 & Biten ska böjas från längden 114,3 mm tills den böjda delen är vinklad 78 grader mot den andra halvan. & Kantvikmaskin & Vinkelinstrument \\ \addlinespace
6 & Sidan där de två kanterna kapades i steg 4 ska nu böjas tills den är 125 grader vinklat mot den oböjda positionen. & Kantvikmaskin & Vinkelinstrument \\ \addlinespace
7 & De två hålen borras och de ska vara parallellt lagda med varandra mellan ett avstånd på 34 mm, och 8 mm från vardera kanter. Hålen ska ha en diameter på 8mm och centrumen bör först markeras med en större pinnfräs innan 8mm pinnfräsen borras igenom metallplåten. & Borrmaskin & Pinnfräs (8mm) \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\caption{De kända variablerna som krävs för att få fram figurens tyngdpunkt där $A$ står för area.}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I will use `tabulary` to use the L column, because in a narrow column the text looks better without full justification. In other cases could be also convenient because provide also R, C and J columns, that unlike X columns, can have different aligns but also different automatic widths without make esoteric tricks. Other reason to use this package instead of `tabularx` is that you do not set the table width, but only a maximum width, so when the table contents are not enough, the table is not fully expanded (some people regard this like a bug, but is really a feature. Expand unnecessarily the width of a table is a bad practice, IMHO).

On the other hand, some space between rows could improve the readability of the table. You can use some like `\setlength\extrarowheight{1ex}` or  `\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.7}` before the table, or to add space only between some rows, end the rows with some like `\\[1ex]`, or better,  `\addlinespace[1ex]` using `booktabs`.

[image: mwe]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabulary,booktabs}
\usepackage[swedish]{babel} 
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
`\setlength\extrarowheight{1ex}`
\begin{tabulary}{\linewidth}{@{}cLll@{}}\toprule 
Steg & Action & Maskin & Verktyg \\\midrule
1 & Börja med att kapa av en rimlig bit för mobilstället & Kapsåg & Klämmare \\
2 & Ställ metallbiten på kapsågsmaskinen så att längden blir 197,5 mm långt och den ska spännas fast med en klämmare. Detta är bara för att komma nära längden så mycket som möjligt. Sedan görs samma metod för bredden, som är 50 mm. & Kapsåg & Klämmare \\
3 & Ställ x, y och z för fräsmaskinen så att metallbiten får den exakta längden och bredden. & Fräsmaskin & Klämmare \\
4 & Kap av två av kanterna så att de två kanterna får en rundare kant och inte 90 grader. & Fräsmaskin & Klämmare \\
5 & Biten ska böjas från längden 114,3 mm tills den böjda delen är vinklad 78 grader mot den andra halvan. & Kantvikmaskin & Vinkelinstrument \\
6 & Sidan där de två kanterna kapades i steg 4 ska nu böjas tills den är 125 grader vinklat mot den oböjda positionen. & Kantvikmaskin & Vinkelinstrument \\
7 & De två hålen borras och de ska vara parallellt lagda med varandra mellan ett avstånd på 34 mm, och 8 mm från vardera kanter. Hålen ska ha en diameter på 8mm och centrumen bör först markeras med en större pinnfräs innan 8mm pinnfräsen borras igenom metallplåten. & Borrmaskin & Pinnfräs (8mm) \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabulary}
\caption{De kända variablerna som krävs för att få fram figurens tyngdpunkt där $A$ står för area.}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```